# .NET Shell Control Library

Tags: .net, controls

Looking for a good quality .NET Control library that provides shell capabilities such as folder trees, item lists, right click, file context menu, and OLE drag/drop.

**Update:** (I am asking this for someone else) Specifically want to provide the list of "files" which may be from numerous locations (the results of a search). And then have the explorer like behavior with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [Gong Solutions Shell Library](http://gong-shell.sourceforge.net/index.php) ?

It's open source (GPL), so you should be able to extend it however you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

ShellMegaPack from LogicNPSoftware

http://www.ssware.com/megapack.htm  I've used them before and they give you everything you need to implement Windows Explorer capabilities. Very customizable as well.

Comment: Played with that control set previously. While it works perfectly for recreating windows explorer, it doesn't allow for extending that functionality as desired.  Thanks though.